# TypeError: 'Pagination' object is not iterable' in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use .iter_pages() method to navigate between the pages , but an error
TypeError: 'Pagination' object is not iterable' is showing

My code :

```
@app.route("/home")
@app.route("/",methods=["GET"])
def posts():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1 , type=int)
    all_posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(page=page , per_page=3)
    return render_template("index.html" , posts=all_posts)
```

And in my template, I am using this line of code

```
{% for page_num in posts.iter_pages(left_edge=1 , right_edge=1 , left_current=1 , right_current=2) %}
```

issue :

```
TypeError: 'Pagination' object is not iterable
```